# How do I set SVG background inline?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to define SVG inline? For example, I can use this CSS to define external SVG for a button background in CSS but I don't know how to do this inline:

```
<input id="Button867" type="button" value="Button" class="buttonSkin">

.buttonSkin {
    background: url(assets/svg/button_skin_up.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
}

.buttonSkin:hover {
    background: url(assets/svg/button_skin_over.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
}

.buttonSkin:active {
    background: url(assets/svg/button_skin_down.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Using BigBadaBooms suggestion I should be able to do the following:

```
<input id="Button867" type="button" value="Button" class="buttonBackgroundSkin">

.buttonBackgroundSkin {
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,<--base64 encoded SVG file-->);
    border: 0px;
}

.buttonBackgroundSkin:hover {
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,<--base64 encoded SVG file-->);
    border: 0px;
}

.buttonBackgroundSkin:active {
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,<--base64 encoded SVG file-->);
    border: 0px;
}
```

I'll look into this more. I was really looking for something like this:

```
<input id="Button867" type="button" value="Button" class="buttonBackgroundSkin">
   <background-image>
      <svg>
       ... 
      </svg>
   <background-image>
   <background-image:hover>
      <svg>
       ... 
      </svg>
   <background-image:hover>
</input>
```

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a data URL.  Something like:

```
background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,<--base64 encoded SVG file-->);
```

You can find many online base64 encoders by googling.  Use one of them to encode your SVG file and then paste it into the place indicated above.

Comment: nice user name. I think I see what you're saying. I'll add a example in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert address to SVG into src attribute of img tag

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg" alt="">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b5pw2/)
But same browsers doesn't support this [link to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/svg-img)

Maybe this example can help to you:
HTML

```
<a href="#">
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />
  <circle class="hover" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.hover{display:none;}
a:hover .hover{display:block}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vA79u/)

Comment: Hi @Anon, I was looking for something inline, not a reference to an SVG file. See OP.